# No Qt.UserRole in PyQt6

Tags: qt, delegates, progress-bar, pyqt6

I'm trying to implement a basic progress bar using a delegate within a TreeView widget. I've double-checked the official documentation, and confirmed that the `UserRole` is supposed to be contained in `PyQt6.QtCore.Qt`. However, I always get the error upon trying to launch the code

> AttributeError: type object 'Qt' has no attribute 'DisplayRole'

How can I solve this problem?

```
import sys
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt

print(Qt.UserRole)


class ProgressBarDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        # Get the data for the item
        progress = index.data(Qt.UserRole)

        # Draw the progress bar
        painter.save()
        rect = option.rect
        rect.setWidth(int(rect.width() * progress))
        painter.fillRect(rect, QtGui.QColor("#00c0ff"))
        painter.restore()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Set up the tree view
        self.tree_view = QtWidgets.QTreeView(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tree_view)

        # Set up the model
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.tree_view.setModel(self.model)

        # Add some items to the model
        for i in range(10):
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem("Item {}".format(i))
            progress = i / 10
            item.setData(progress, Qt.UserRole)
            self.model.appendRow(item)

        # Set the delegate for the progress bar column
        self.tree_view.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, ProgressBarDelegate(self))


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Update:
I've tried `Qt.ItemDataRole.UserRole`, it didn't give the error above, but the progress bar didn't show up.

Comment: `Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole` etc..

Comment: @musicamante I've tried `Qt.ItemDataRole.UserRole`, it didn't give this error, but the progress bar didn't show up.

Comment: That's because you're setting the delegate for the wrong column: indexes always start from 0 and right now your model only uses a single column. Note that standard item views and models work differently than QTreeWidget, items and indexes are not grouped by row. If you want to show more than one column, you have to set the model with two columns, and you must properly add a *second* QStandardItem to the same row. Also note that in order to properly show multiple columns for a child item, **all** its parent items must also have at least the same number of columns.

Comment: Note that I updated the comment to add further details. Also, since the linked answer is valid for your question, you should accept its duplicate (there should be a button at the top of this post).

Comment: Unfortunately, I've already not accepted it as a duplicate. Is there a way to re-access that dialog? At the same time, I'm afraid that the answer that you consider duplicate may not be easily searchable as relevant.

Comment: I can only retract my vote, but then I'll not be able to add it again. Maybe somebody else with enough reputation will be able to do that.